# Subsetting and assignment on several columns of a data table

Tags: r, data.table

Lets say I have a data table like the one below:

```
library(data.table)
N = 10
x = data.table(id = 1:N, 
               segm = sample(c("A","B","C"),N,replace=T), r = rnorm(N,20,5),
               aa = sample(0:1,N,replace=T), ab = sample(0:1,N,replace=T), 
               ba = sample(0:1,N,replace=T), bb = sample(0:1,N,replace=T))
```

I'd like to know how to substitute the 1 values for `NA` but only for the columns `aa`, `ab`, `ba` and `bb` using the data table package. I know how to do this using data frame.

I tried using the following:

```
f = c("aa","ab","ba","bb") 
x[,f,with=F][x[,f,with=F]==1] <- "NA"
```

but I'm getting an error: `Error in [<-.data.table(*tmp*, , f, with = F, value = list(aa = c("0",  : unused argument (with = F)`

To sum up, my question is: How can I subset and assign on several columns of a data table at the same time.

The line of code:

```
 x[f==1,f:="NA"]
```

is just not working. Why?

Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using a `for()` loop here.

Given the nature of your problem,  with a different subset of rows being operated on in each of the four columns, you're going to need to use *some* sort of loop; you might as well construct an explicit one that allows you to take full advantage of **data.table**'s modify-by-reference `:=` operator.

```
for (i in f)
    x[get(i)==1, (i):=NA]

x
#     id segm         r aa ab ba bb
#  1:  1    C 15.203246 NA NA  0  0
#  2:  2    B 23.536583 NA  0  0 NA
#  3:  3    A 16.404203 NA  0 NA  0
#  4:  4    A 18.673618  0  0 NA NA
#  5:  5    C 30.528967 NA  0 NA NA
#  6:  6    A 18.887781  0 NA NA NA
#  7:  7    C 24.476124  0  0 NA NA
#  8:  8    B 26.862686  0  0 NA  0
#  9:  9    C  9.047837  0  0  0 NA
# 10: 10    C 17.532379  0  0 NA NA
```

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to accomplish this in another way, for this particular case:

```
x[, (f) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x * (x | NA)), .SDcols=f]
```

We use the fact that `TRUE | NA = TRUE` and `FALSE | NA = NA` here. The `(` in the LHS of `:=` sees it as an expression (rather than a variable name) and therefore evaluates it to obtain the columns contained in it. Specifying `.SDcols` provides `.SD` with just the columns `f`, what we want. And we apply this hack of a function to replace each column, by reference.

---

```
DT[f == 1, f := NA]
```

doesn't work because:

Let's write your expression as `DT[i, LHS := RHS]`. `i` being an expression gets evaluated within the scope of `DT`. `[.data.table` tries to find a column `f` within the scope of `DT` and since there isn't any, it'll try to find in the calling scope and gets the value stored in it, which then becomes: `c("aa", "ab", "ba", "bb") == 1`. This evaluates to `FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE` resulting in an empty `data.table` - the assignment in `j` will have no effect.

Also note the `(` in `LHS` in my answer. This is so that we can still conveniently use `DT[, f := val]` where `f` **is** the column name.

Comment: (+1) I not always understand everything you say but it always works :)